# Getting error:Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms when using in windows 10 , firefox version 25-45, selenium-java 2.0-2.53

Tags: selenium

'org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
1465984002451   addons.manager  DEBUG   Application has been upgraded
1465984002483   addons.xpi  DEBUG   startup
1465984002484   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local

How to come up with these error .
I tried a lot but not get succeed till now . Please help me .
I have decrease selenium version also , error is still there .

Comment: What do you mean by all version of firefox driver??

Comment: try using the default port - `4723` also make sure any firewall is not preventing such a session

Comment: What is the version of firefox you are using?

Comment: firefox version 30 , Selenium-java 2.53

Comment: After restarting the OS its working properly after 5-10 minutes again showing error .

Comment: It is simply a timeout. Selenium waits for an event and it doesn't occur. You can increase timeout by `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` 45 to any value more.  Also you will have more details of error below. Please post the complete stacktrace

Comment: i have already tried by this process also but not success .                       Firefox is opening but not navigating to any url . if i am restarting the system after that its working fine upto 5 to 10 minutes , after that again i am going to execute any script its showing error: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms